# Measuring the "Sensitivity" of a Function?

Tags: probability

Consider the definition of the Fisher Information (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information) below :

**Why does the "expected value of the square of the second derivative of the log likelihood function (for some probability distribution)" tell us about the "information that an observed random variable carries about some hidden parameter" or how "sensitive the log likelihood function is"?**

Just by looking at the mathematical formula of the Fisher Information in isolation, how am I supposed to recognize that this is a formula that is describing the informativeness of the data, or the sensitivity of the likelihood function to changes in the parameter?

I can understand that:

- For some probability distributions, some random points are "more informative" about the probability distribution compared to other random points (e.g. Uniform Distribution vs Normal Distribution).
- Within the formula of the Fisher Information, I can recognize that the first derivative is measuring the "slope" of the likelihood function and thus could be used to quantify "rate of change" - and the second derivative is measuring the "curvature" of the likelihood function.

**But how does the "expected value of the square of the second derivative of the log likelihood function (for some probability distribution)" relate to amount of information and the sensitivity?**

I have never been able to make this connection - can someone please help me understand this?

Thanks!

Notes:

- In statistics, we know that the inverse of the Fisher Information is equal to the inverse of the variance.
- We also know that likelihood functions with a "large Fisher Information" are said to be more sensitive to the data - but I don't know why this is

Comment: For the case of a normal random variable, this is equivalent to the precision (the inverse of the variance). The less variance, the more "precise" is your information. This generalizes to multivariate normal.

Comment: @ PC1: thank you for your answer! If you have time, could you please elaborate on this comment in an answer? thank you so much!

Comment: Maybe best is to read [Cramér–Rao bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramér–Rao_bound), it embodies the intuition behind the precision of a distribution. Also note that the normal distribution is the one for which you obtain the equality.